# What algorithms can I use to optimize in a high dimensional discrete space in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, datagrid, solver, discrete-mathematics

I have a matrix D representing a grid of points in a high dimensional space. The number of rows is the number of datapoints, and the number of columns is the dimensionality of the space.

I have a function f that can take a row of D and outputs a single float value. The function f would be smooth if it could be evaluated at points outside the grid. The function f may have multiple zeros.

I want to find points (row instances) where the function f is close to zero. I do not want to evaluate the function at every row in D exhaustively, because there are too many rows.

What algorithm and libraries do you recommend for this problem? I would prefer using existing Python libraries to simplify the implementation. I am also interested in finding multiple zeros.

So start with, I was thinking of using some type of simplex search, maybe running it multiple times from different starting locations (multi-start). I do not know of libraries that could work on the problem the way it is posed, though.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

as you do not want to evaluate **f** too many time, your problem looks like a **black-box function** problem. To optimize such a function, there are many tools, like bayesian optimization, that will modelize the shape of your function using gaussian processes (look at "kriging" in wikipedia). If your function **f** values are 1-dimensional, I recommand you to use smt : https://github.com/SMTorg/SMT

If there are many objectives, I developped a tool : https://github.com/RobinGRAPIN/smoot. Look at the notebook tutorial to understand its functionment :)